# can't run "lspci" command using rsh from a windows batch file

Tags: command-line, rsh

I've made a batch file on a Windows machine, with the following command:

```
rsh hdvg-1 -l root lspci
```

The `hdvg-1` is the name of the Linux machine on the network.

But what I get in result is: `command not found`. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Perhaps also help me to use the following command in order to filter the lspci result:

```
lspci | grep 'certain string
```

Comment: Is there some specific problem with the `grep`? That pipe seems to look like it should work...

Comment: i dont know, i first want to get the "lspci" command running...

Answer (score 1):

[`rsh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsh) expects the hostname after the options, e.g.,

```
rsh  -l root hdvg-1 lspci
```

Otherwise, it is trying to execute **`"-l"`**.

The `grep` command has an unbalanced quote, and should be something like

```
lspci | grep 'certain string'
```

If you want to verify that the `lspci` command is available on your machine, you could do just

```
rsh  -l root hdvg-1
```

to get a shell, and then type `lspci` in that shell.  By the way, since `rsh` is likely an alias for `ssh`, you should use `ssh` to avoid confusion.

Another source of confusion is that when using remote shells, your `$PATH` environment variable may not be set the same as if you logged in normally.  According to a discussion in [rsh server "script..." which $PATH is used ?](http://www.unix.com/aix/116932-rsh-server-script-path-used.html),

> `rsh` requires fully qualified names of executables, scripts to be safe. It uses `/usr/bin/sh` (whatever that evaluates to on the remote server), and the **`PATH`** is usually limited:
>   **`/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`**

On your remote machine, `lspci` may not be in the `$PATH` used for the remote call.

Further reading:

- [ssh — OpenSSH SSH client (remote login program)](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh)
- [Rsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490992.aspx)  (Microsoft TechNet)

Comment: dear thomas, i tried your command, but still i get "command not found"...

Comment: the exact message is:  lspci: command not found

Comment: when i try only "rsh -l root hdvg-1" on the batch file, i get a window opened and than immidietly closed...

Comment: It might help to explain which rsh/ssh client you are using (which would clarify why you "get a window").  If you were having problems with logging in, then it's odd that you get as far as the "command not found" message.

Comment: as i explained, i do the the following: open a notepad, write the code in it, rename the notepad file as .bat, and then double cliick it.

Comment: There's more than one program that you could be using.  It could even be the [native Windows client](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170276).

Comment: ok, i do have a putty, and there i can login to the system and perform the lspci. but i really want to avoid doing it, and to make something more automatic.